# 'Conference' type operations using Bluetooth?

Tags: bluetooth

Is it possible to implement Bluetooth devices to provide conference rather than one-to-one operation.
Are there any development toolkits that will allow me to configure BT devices in this way, or modifications that can be done to the BT stack or an add-on protocol.
I need to configure several Bluetooth adaptors to simultaneously communicate with one another. I think BT allows up to 10 'pico-nets' but I need specialiced advice.
I would welcome any links to resources, or replies from Bluetooth experts.
Thanks in anticipation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've heard of something close to this, called a [piconet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piconet). Googling "bluetooth piconet" should point you in the right direction.

A master device can be networked in this way with up to 255 slave devices, but only 7 can be active at any one time. This is more of a one-to-many communication than many-to-many, but could potentially be approximated by having the master device act like a network switch.

**Update:** I just read that slaves in one piconet can participate in another piconet as either a master or slave, forming a "[scatternet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scatternet)".